# What is the difference between where, mask and df[S>0] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say if I want to we slice the the dataframe with the condition (element > 0) :

How does where, mask, df[S>0] behave?

Thanks

Comment: These are things you can easily run and check yourself.... where and mask insert NaNs (or any user specified default), while df[S > 0] removes rows that do not follow that condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [**`where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Takes a boolean array or pandas object that keeps the values where the input is `True` and replaces them with `np.nan`.  Optionally, you can pass an `other` argument that will be used to fill in instead of `np.nan`

#### [**`mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

The same thing as `where` except it keeps the `False` and replaces the `True`

#### `df[S > 0]`

Filters `df` if `S` is a series.  Otherwise works like `where`.